# Describing solution of particular ODE with small parameter

Tags: differential-equations

I have differential equation (1) $x''+2\epsilon \nu x'+x+\epsilon x^3=0$. I try to solve it using a method of multiple scales. So $x=x(t)=x(T_0,T_1,T_2,...,T_n)$, where $T_i=\epsilon^i t$.

Then $\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{\partial }{\partial T_0}+\epsilon \frac{\partial }{\partial T_1}+\epsilon^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial T_2}+...+\epsilon^n \frac{\partial }{\partial T_n}=D_0+\epsilon D_1+...+\epsilon^n D_n$

and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}=(\frac{\partial }{\partial T_0}+\epsilon \frac{\partial }{\partial T_1}+\epsilon^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial T_2}+...+\epsilon^n \frac{\partial }{\partial T_n})^2=(D_0+\epsilon D_1+...+\epsilon^n D_n)^2$

Using $x=x_0+\epsilon x_1+\epsilon^2 x_2+...$ we can rewrite (1):
$$D_0^2x_0+2\epsilon D_0 D_1 x_0+...+\epsilon D_0^2 x_1+...+2\epsilon \nu D_0 x_0+...+x_0+\epsilon x_1+...+\epsilon x_0^3+3\epsilon^2 x_0^2 x_1+...=0$$

How can I describe these(where $n$ is a variable) using Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, tim! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely what [`AsymptoticDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html) does:

```
X[t_] = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{x''[t] + 2 ε ν x'[t] + x[t] + ε x[t]^3 == 0,
                               x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, 
                              x[t], t, {ε, 0, 3}]
```

(huge output to third order in $\varepsilon$)

Check that this solution satisfies the differential equation to third order in $\varepsilon$:

```
Series[X''[t] + 2 ε ν X'[t] + X[t] + ε X[t]^3, {ε, 0, 3}]
```

> O[ε]^4

---

If you don't have access to `AsymptoticDSolveValue`, you can do it yourself iteratively (to $m^{\text{th}}$ order):

```
m = 3;
x[t_] = Sum[X[n, t]*ε^n, {n, 0, m}];

Do[X[n, t_] = X[n, t] /. FullSimplify[First[
  DSolve[Normal[Series[{x''[t] + 2 ε ν x'[t] + x[t] + ε x[t]^3 == 0,
                        x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, {ε, 0, n}]],
         X[n, t], t]]], {n, 0, m}];
```

Now you can look at the resulting $x(t)$:

```
x[t]
```

(huge output to third order in $\varepsilon$)

Check that this solution satisfies the differential equation to third order in $\varepsilon$:

```
Series[{x''[t] + 2 ε ν x'[t] + x[t] + ε x[t]^3, x[0], x'[0]}, {ε, 0, m}]
```

> O[ε]^4

Comment: Thank you, it's easier than I thought. But I consider that there are no so new functions on my university computers. How can I do it without any new functionality?

Comment: @timbars you can use it free in [wolfram development platform](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook?ext=nb)

Comment: I’d ask your system administrators if they could upgrade. They might have a site license that includes updates, but just haven’t gotten around to it yet, since v12 was just released.

Comment: I do not need a solution to this problem(because it's incorrect), I just want to rewrite it as a partial differential equation(the last equation in my question)

Comment: How about just using part of the second solution: `m = 3; x[t_] = Sum[X[n, t]*ε^n, {n, 0, m}];` and then look at `Series[x''[t] + 2 ε ν x'[t] + x[t] + ε x[t]^3 == 0, {ε, 0, m}]`

Comment: Or even `Table[SeriesCoefficient[x''[t] + 2 ε ν x'[t] + x[t] + ε x[t]^3, {ε, 0, i}] == 0, {i, 0, m}]` to get an explicit list of equations instead of a series-expansion.

Comment: I want $x=x(T_1,T_2,...)$, not $x=x(t)$

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. It seems natural to do a perturbation expansion for small $\epsilon$, which gives a series expansion of the solution $x$. What you seem to want is a series expansion for small $t$, which I don't understand, as $t$ need not be small in a perturbation expansion. So from this point of view I was interpreting parts of your write-up as an XY problem and tried to go for X instead. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You could of course take my above solution `X[t]` and series-expand it for small $t$ with `Series[X[t], {epsilon, 0, 3}]`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I want to define operators $\frac{d}{dt}\;$ and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$, as described in question. For better understanding, you can find a mathematical description of "the method of multiple scales"